# am learning to do restful web services while implementing i got following error help me to resolve

Tags: java, apache, rest, tomcat, restful-authentication

Screenshot of source code and exception:
[image: Screenshot 1]

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1120)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:738)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:693)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1128)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
... 6 more

Mar 30, 2016 10:38:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:693)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:738)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1128)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
... 11 more
```

Screenshot of the configuration file *web.xml*:
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: It should be the problem of your setting. Put it on or no one can help you.

Comment: please add this `stackTrace` in Code

Comment: Please provide the Java code that raises this exception and describe under which circumstances the exceptions is raised.

Comment: Generally, avoid screenshots and paste stuff as text...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception is seen when the JRE version of Eclipse and Tomcat are not compatible. 
**Solution**- Either change Eclipse one as that of Tomcat or vice-versa.
You can check for JAVA_HOME by looking at tomcat startup.bat file.

Comment: am using jre version 1.8.0_45, and  can you please tell compatible version of tomcat?